# JQuery .html() function seems to cache unecessarily in IE

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer, caching, partial-views

I have this small problem with my MVC program, when run with IE:

I have a JQuery function which goes to a controller to get a partial view, which is loaded into a destination `<div>` element.

```
function editSkills(projectId, roleId) {
    $.get('../../Project/EditSkills?projectID=' + projectId + '&roleID=' + roleId, function (data) {
        $('#infoPanel').html(data);
    });
}
```

The `EditSkills()` function in the Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult EditSkills(int projectID, int roleID)
{
    //various pieces of logic

    return PartialView("EditSkills");
}
```

It seems to work correctly the first time the function is called, but subsequent calls return the same information, instantly, even if the underlying data has been modified.

I suspect this is a caching problem (as IE is supposedly overzealous in doing so). As it works perfectly fine in Chrome etc.

Are there any options to prevent caching in this case?

Comment: It's not the `.html` function at fault here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following

```
function editSkills(projectId, roleId) {
 $.ajax({
        url: '../../Project/EditSkills?projectID=' + projectId + '&roleID=' +    roleId,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
             $('#infoPanel').html(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this cache-busting is achieved by adding an (ever-changing) parameter to the querystring so that the url is unique and its resource is treated as distinct by the browser. From the docs: "It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters."

Comment: Works. Like. A Dream! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using $.get, hence the caching. Internally it uses $.ajax, which you should be using with cache:false to avoid caching.

If you insist on using $.get, attach some random number to get parameter to avoid caching i all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using get, i think it would be better if you use $.ajax instead ($.get is a shorthand for $.ajax). In the ajax method you can set the "cache" parameter to false. Something like this:

```
function editSkills(projectId, roleId) {
  $.ajax({
    url:'../../Project/EditSkills?projectID=' + projectId + '&roleID=' + roleId,
    type:'GET',
    cache:false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $('#infoPanel').html(data);
    }
  });
```

}